# Exponent of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I got this problem:

Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb R)$ such that $A = -A^T$. Prove that $e^A$ is an orthogonal matrix.

I succeeded in showing that $e^{(A^T)}e^A=I$ but did not succeed in proving that 
$e^{(A^T)}=(e^A)^T$. Any suggestions? Thanks to helpers!

Comment: Consider definition and formula : $e^A  =\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{i!}A^i$ and $(XY)^T = Y^TX^T$

Comment: I still have a problem. Could you explain more?

Answer (score 6):

I will add details :
    $$ [e^A]^T = \bigg[\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{i!}A^i \bigg]^T = \sum_{i=0
}^\infty \frac{1}{i!} (A^i)^T=\sum_{i=0
}^\infty \frac{1}{i!} (A^T)^i  =e^{A^T} $$